# Error occurred when migration authenticate ASP.NET Core with SQL Server 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

There are some errors when I migration, could someone please to help me

> Column, parameter, or variable #9: Cannot find data type datetimeoffset

Because type of `LockoutEnd` is `datetimeoffset`, SQL Server 2017 doesn't have type `datetimeoffset`.

After using

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<identityuser>(entity => entity.Ignore(x => x.LockoutEnd));
}
```

to ignore `LockoutEnd` to try to migrate with database, another error occurs:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

with this SQL command:

> Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [RoleNameIndex] 
ON [AspNetRoles] ([NormalizedName]) 
WHERE [NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL;
```

I have researched but can't find any solution. Please help me.

The website https://auth0.com/blog/asp-dot-net-core-authentication-tutorial/ that I have followed

Comment: SQL Server 2017 **most DEFINITELY** has the `DATETIMEOFFSET` datatype available! Are you **sure** you running against a 2017 version? What output do you get from `SELECT @@VERSION` ?? Maybe you're just using Mgmt Studio 2017, but running against an older version of SQL Server (the database **engine**) ....

Comment: Thank you very much. As you said. My version of sql server is 2005. After install sql server 2017. My issue was solved. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. SQL Server *2005* did not (yet) have `DATETIMEOFFSET` and filtered indexes (both introduced in SQL Server **2008**)